# Troubleshooting "No such file or directory" when running `php app/console doctrine:schema:create`

Tags: php, mysql, doctrine-orm, symfony

I am new to Symfony2 (beta4) and Doctrine and am having issues when i try to create the DB schema via command line.

Here's the error:

```
$ php app/console doctrine:schema:create

Creating database schema...

[PDOException]                                    
SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] No such file or directory  

[ErrorException]                                                                                          
Warning: PDO::__construct(): [2002] No such file or directory (trying to connect via unix:///var/mysql/mysql.sock) 
in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/sf-test-2/vendor/doctrine-dbal/lib/Doctrine/DBAL/Driver/PDOConnection.php line 36
```

The mysql database settings are correctly inserted in the config/parameters.ini file.

And here's the Doctrine configuration in config.yml

```
# Doctrine Configuration
doctrine:
    dbal:
        driver:   %database_driver%
        host:     %database_host%
        dbname:   %database_name%
        user:     %database_user%
        password: %database_password%

    orm:
        auto_generate_proxy_classes: %kernel.debug%
        auto_mapping: true
```

And the entity (i made only one to test it)

```
<?php
// src/Acme/NewsBundle/Entity/Article.php
namespace Acme\NewsBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\Table(name="articles")
 */
class Article
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
protected $id;

/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="string", length="255")
 */
protected $title;

/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="text")
 */
protected $body;

/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="string", length="255")
 */
protected $author;

/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="date")
 */
protected $date;
}
?>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I fixed it by following this small tutorial: http://andreys.info/blog/2007-11-07/configuring-terminal-to-work-with-mamp-mysql-on-leopard

**[EDIT]:
I modified the right php.ini and everything's working fine now.**

Now I get the following error:

```
[Exception]                                                                                            
 DateTime::__construct(): It is not safe to rely on the system's timezone settings.
 You are *required* to use the date.timezone setting or the date_default_timezone_set() function.
 In case you used any of those methods and you are still getting this warning, you most likely misspelled the timezone identifier.
 We selected 'Europe/Berlin' for 'CEST/2.0/DST' instead
```

Here's the date.timezone config in php.ini

```
date.timezone = "Europe/Paris"
```

I'll try to figure it out myself but if any of you know how to fix it don't hesitate to comment on this. Thanks!

Comment: I typed php -ini in the terminal and the setting date.timezone has no value. I'll look for the file path, see what php.ini file is used by the console.

Answer (score 167):

Just today I had a similar situation (but in other context, I was trying to create entities from db).

I solved it simply modifying the `database_host` from `"localhost"` to `"127.0.0.1"` in the parameters.ini file.

I think my Mysql instance is running only via TCP and not socket and because this when use `database_host="localhost"` it fails.

Comment: Beware, in the way of MySQL connects, we realized at work that there is a difference between the connection string host "localhost" and 127.0.0.1.  With SSH proxy, we have to prevent writing localhost.  Hope it's useful.

Comment: @neil: Thx. I had this problem on my mac. 127.0.0.1 safed my day ;)

Comment: I also had to explicitly define the MySQL port to get this to work. My MAMP runs on port 8889, so my database_host ended up looking like: `127.0.0.1:8889`. Hope this helps someone else.

Answer (score 19):

Try to add this line

```
unix_socket: /tmp/mysql.sock
```

into your config.yml file > doctrine > dbal just after the password line.

Comment: This version worked for me: unix_socket: /Applications/MAMP/tmp/mysql/mysql.sock

Comment: Always use socket, because it little faster

Answer (score 11):

I changed 'host'=> 'localhost' to 'host'=> '127.0.0.1' on app/config/database.php and everything is working correctly

Answer (score 2):

The problem for me was the `mysql.default_socket` setting in PHP.INI defaults to a different location than where MySQL actually puts that file.

Instead of editing the config files, I created an alias in the location that PHP is looking that connects to the real mysql.sock.

Just run these two commands (no restart needed):

```
mkdir /var/mysql
ln -s /tmp/mysql.sock /var/mysql/mysql.sock
```

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes you may got several solution for location path of mysql.lock. But I think the best solution is just see the location path of mysql using php `phpinfo()` function.

Note: if you are not familar with `phpinfo()`, then just create a file give any name and include content of that file like this

```
<?php
phpinfo();
?>
```

run this file and get the path of mysql.lock file. I think it will help.

Answer (score 0):

Worth checking to see if Mysql is running too.

Answer (score 0):

Too late but hope it can help someone as well.

I am using Vagrant

Just change `localhost` to `127.0.0.1` AND change the port to `3333`

worked perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

I think just restart the mysql, and apache, that's work for me.

Answer (score 0):

Restarting mysql worked for me:

`sudo /etc/init.d/mysql restart`

Answer (score 0):

Had the same issue "SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] No such file or directory" on symfony 3.2.9 on deployment

I fixed it by changing the database_host value from "localhost" to my server IP on my parameters.yml file

but I had this another error message when trying to run commandline by SSH:

[Doctrine\DBAL\Exception\ConnectionException]
  An exception occured in driver: SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Connection refused

I finaly fix it by adding these 2 lines on my config.yml file in Doctrine configuration section :

```
unix_socket: /var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock
server_version: '5.5'
```

all my final doctrine configuration is like this:

```
doctrine:
    dbal:
        driver: pdo_mysql
        host: '%database_host%'
        port: '%database_port%'
        dbname: '%database_name%'
        user: '%database_user%'
        password: '%database_password%'
        unix_socket: /var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock
        server_version: '5.5'
        charset: UTF8
```

hopefully this helps

Answer (score 0):

**Laravel** **.env** add **DB_SOCKET** with path to **mysql.sock**

```
DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=localhost
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=database
DB_USERNAME=root
DB_PASSWORD=mypassword

DB_SOCKET=/Users/username/Library/Containers/MAMP/mysql/tmp/mysql.sock
```

or add unix_socket in PDO

```
PDO('mysql:host=localhost;port=3306;unix_socket=/Users/username/Library/Containers/MAMP/mysql/tmp/mysql.sock', root, mypassword);
```