# Uncaught PDOException while using Doctrine 2 CLI in ZF2

Tags: php, doctrine-orm, zend-framework2, zend-server

I am getting an uncaught PDO Exception while trying to use the doctrine CLI. I am following [marco's tutorial](http://marco-pivetta.com/doctrine-orm-zf2-tutorial/#/).

**My configuration is :** 
ZF 2.5.1 with PHP version 5.5.21

### Zend Server 8.0.2

**Exception Encountered:**

> Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] No such file or directory' in /usr/local/zend/apache2/htdocs/website-/vendor/doctrine/dbal/lib/Doctrine/DBAL/Driver/PDOConnection.php:43
>   *Stack trace:*
>   0. /usr/local/zend/apache2/htdocs/website-/vendor/doctrine/dbal/lib/Doctrine/DBAL/Driver/PDOConnection.php(43): PDO->__construct('mysql:host=loca...', 'root', '', Array)
>   1. /usr/local/zend/apache2/htdocs/website-/vendor/doctrine/dbal/lib/Doctrine/DBAL/Driver/PDOMySql/Driver.php(45): Doctrine\DBAL\Driver\PDOConnection->__construct('mysql:host=loca...', 'root', '', Array)
>   2. /usr/local/zend/apache2/htdocs/website-/vendor/doctrine/dbal/lib/Doctrine/DBAL/Connection.php(360): Doctrine\DBAL\Driver\PDOMySql\Driver->connect(Array, 'root', '', Array)
>   3. /usr/local/zend/apache2/htdocs/website-/vendor/doctrine/dbal/lib/Doctrine/DBAL/Connection.php(429): Doctrine\DBAL\Connection->connect()
>   4. /usr/local/zend/apache2/htdocs/website-/vendor/doctrine/dba in /usr/local/zend/apache2/htdocs/website-/vendor/zendframework/zend-servicemanager/src/ServiceManager.php on line 946

---

Can anyone help or give me any suggestion please?

Additional Information:

1. Command used for accessing Doctrine CLI:

   `./vendor/bin/doctrine-module orm:validate-schema`
2. Contents of /vendor/bin/:

> ABHI  staff    57B Jun  6 00:47 classmap_generator.php -> ../zendframework/zendframework/bin/classmap_generator.php
>    ABHI  staff    28B Jun 16 19:46 doctrine -> ../doctrine/orm/bin/doctrine
>    ABHI  staff    34B Jun 16 19:46 doctrine-dbal -> ../doctrine/dbal/bin/doctrine-dbal
>    ABHI  staff    47B Jun 16 19:46 doctrine-module -> ../doctrine/doctrine-module/bin/doctrine-module
>    ABHI  staff    32B Jun 16 19:46 doctrine.php -> ../doctrine/orm/bin/doctrine.php
>    root  staff    26B Jun 16 20:26 phpunit -> ../phpunit/phpunit/phpunit
>    ABHI  staff    58B Jun  6 00:47 pluginmap_generator.php -> ../zendframework/zendframework/bin/pluginmap_generator.php
>    ABHI  staff    60B Jun  6 00:47 templatemap_generator.php -> ../zendframework/zendframework/bin/templatemap_generator.php
>    ABHI  staff    30B Jun 16 19:52 zf.php -> ../zendframework/zftool/zf.php

3. Snippet from doctrine-module file:

   ```
   /* @var $cli \Symfony\Component\Console\Application */
   $cli = $application->getServiceManager()->get('doctrine.cli');
   exit($cli->run());
   ```
4. Throwing error in the following function in the PDOConnection.php file:

   ```
   public function __construct($dsn, $user = null, $password = null, array $options = null)
   {
       try {
           parent::__construct($dsn, $user, $password, $options);
           $this->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_STATEMENT_CLASS, array('Doctrine\DBAL\Driver\PDOStatement', array()));
           $this->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
       } catch (\PDOException $exception) {
           throw new PDOException($exception);
       }
   }
   ```

Comment: Have you looked at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6259424/troubleshooting-no-such-file-or-directory-when-running-php-app-console-doctri/9251924#9251924 ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2412009/starting-with-zend-tutorial-zend-db-adapter-throws-exception-sqlstatehy000

Answer (score 4):

I know it's been a while back now since this question was asked but, thought i'd share a solution still since none was provided.

The error suggests your application can not connect to the database, no database connection found to be precise.

If you have the app hosted and testing on a platform somewhere other than your local instance, then you probably pushed using `GIT` and by default, zf2 has a `.gitignore` file in the `config/autoload` folder that ignores the `local.php` and all other files in that folder with a `.local.php` extension.
Since you are using `DoctrineORM`, though not a requirement but, I'd guess you probably have a `doctrine.local.php` file in the `config/autoload` folder with your database connection.

**Fixes:**

1. You could use ftp instead to upload the database connection file `local.php` or any other file that carries your database connection.
2. You could remove the `local.php` file from the `.gitignore` file that probably has your database connection details.
3. You could use the global.php

Hope this helps someone who may face similar issue later on.