# Symfony 4 - SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] No such file or directory

Tags: php, symfony

I've been trying to update my database with a Symfony 4 project.

When, connected in ssh I do `php7.1-cli bin/console doctrine:schema:update`

I have the following error

[image: errors]

I don't know what this means.

Here's my `.env`

[image: .env] and my `doctrine.yaml`

[image: doctrine.ymal]

Comment: It should be sufficient to have the database connection string as URI in the `.env` file. You don't need the config in your yaml files anymore. Also remove the addtional variables like `DATABASE_USER`.

Comment: @Chrisissorry has right, you're configuration is not correct with `.env` usage.
Other thing, you are using mysql and it's possible you need to change `localhost` string need to be change to `127.0.0.1` as explain [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9251924/7256369).